# Inconsistent behavior or input fields value

Tags: jquery, html, forms, input, bpopup

I have a form in a modal window with some custom validation and I serialize the form data 
on a button .click and the forms action is javascript:void() ,now i have an optional input field

```
<input type="text" name="property_id" id="pid" value='' class="optional"/>
```

and I selectively serialize this with

```
var values = $(form).find('input[value!=""]').serialize();
```

now the value attribute of the pid field is not getting  updated when I type in the form
and is not getting submitted.so in the chrome js console  i tried running

```
$("#pid").val()
```

and it gives me whatever I typed in but

```
$("#pid").attr('value')
```

gives me ""

whats the reason for this behavior ? I am ajax loading this form .
EDIT :
I am using bpopup jquery plugin to load the form on a modal window after documen load .
this is the form its in a different html file which is ajax loaded as a popup using bpopup the scripts are linked in this file.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="vmuform" action="javascript:void(0);">
```

The whole code is too long to post here

```
$(function(){
$("#vmusubmit").click(function(){
var uname=
var pass= 
var base = 
var form = $(this).parents('form:first');
console.log(form.attr('id'))
if(form.attr('id') === 
var path=
if(form.attr('id') === 
var path="
if(form.attr('id') === 
var path="

var values = $(form).find('input[value!=""]').serialize();
console.log(values);
$.ajax( {crossDomain: true,
       username:uname,
       password: pass,
       type: "POST",
       url: base+path,
       data: values,
       dataType:"xml",
       success: function( response ) {
           console.log( response );
           var stat=$(response).find('rsp').attr('stat');
           if(stat ==='ok'){
               $('#mod-alert').html("Data successfully added.").addClass("alert-success").removeClass("alert-error").show();
           }
           else
               {
                   $('#mod-alert').html($(response).find('message')).addClass("alert-error").removeClass("alert-success").show();
               }
       }
} );
});

})
```

Comment: $(form) <-- looks for a variable called "form", do you have one?

Comment: Show how your using your AJAX and where exactly you are printing these. Possibly issue with how you use AJAX

Comment: I have removed some snippets from the code ,I am too cranky now to write dummy variables

Answer (score 1):

That is due to `.val() and .attr('value')` are not exactly the same.

The `.attr(..)` is only returns the objects value when the html is created (i.e., the original value).

`.val()` is getting the object's property value which can change many times.

The reason why the value is not submitted even when you type something can be explained only if we see more code. However, the best way to serialize a form and eliminate all the empty values will to clone it.

```
$(form).clone().find('input:text[value=""]').remove().end().serialize();
```

Comment: How is clonning better  as you are using the same selectors ?

Comment: You can see that I am actually removing the empty elements from the cloned form

Comment: Yes but it does not serve any purpose other than what a != or a not selector does .And could you explain what the end does?